# Gradle Task error

Tags: android, json, android-gradle-plugin

I've made a few amendments and now when I try to run my project I'm getting this:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugSources, :app:assembleNoAnalyticsDebug]
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for noAnalyticsDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for noAnalyticsRelease as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for withAnalyticsDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for withAnalyticsRelease as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preNoAnalyticsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkNoAnalyticsDebugManifest
:app:preNoAnalyticsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preWithAnalyticsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preWithAnalyticsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubLzyzsdCircleprogress110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubMarkushiAndroidUi12Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComKlinkerappsAndroidChips100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMelnykovFloatingactionbutton130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComNispokSnackbar2106Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPushbulletAndroidExtensions104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSquareupLeakcanaryLeakcanaryAndroidNoOp13Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItNeokreeMaterialTabs011Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMeLeolinShortcutBadger111Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgLigiSnackengage04Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareNoAnalyticsDebugDependencies
:app:compileNoAnalyticsDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileNoAnalyticsDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeNoAnalyticsDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateNoAnalyticsDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeNoAnalyticsDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processNoAnalyticsDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processNoAnalyticsDebugResources
C:\Users\ajw92\Desktop\New Wifi-Bluetooth-Chat2\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\noAnalytics\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
C:\Users\ajw92\Desktop\New Wifi-Bluetooth-Chat2\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\noAnalytics\debug\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processNoAnalyticsDebugResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Ashley\Android\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I've cleaned and re built the project but still having a issue.

I've tried resolving this myself but I'm struggling.

Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that your app has multiple files with same name `ic_launcher.png` Remove the duplicated file and it will works